# Oracle Decode function results with different formats

Tags: oracle, decode

```
SELECT DECODE (SYSDATE, SYSDATE + 1, NULL, SYSDATE)
  FROM DUAL;


SELECT DECODE (SYSDATE, SYSDATE + 1, TO_DATE (NULL), SYSDATE)
  FROM DUAL;
```

why am i getting the results in different formats from the queries above?

i am using Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "different formats"?  What, exactly, are you seeing these two queries return?

Comment: The problem is the null value. What datatype is that?  The second query will return a date. For the first query it is varchar2(8).

Comment: sorry Justin, the 1st query trims the returning value of sysdate, 2nd returns it with its hour, min etc values. But i think Rene has already solved my problem :)

Comment: To clarify it for everyone, So oracle assigns a Varchar2 datatype to NULL by default, and the datatype of the returning value of decode is the type of the 1st result parameter (i mean 3rd param in my queries), even if the condition will fail and the statement will return the 2nd result parameter(4th in my queries). Am i right?

Comment: This document explains the datatype returned by decode: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm

Comment: The datatype of null is null. Try doing `select dump(null), dump(to_date(null)) from dual;`. In 10g that's showing both as `NULL`, so I don't think that's quite right. I also get exactly the same results from your two queries, in both SQL*Plus and SQL Developer, using both my default NLS_DATE_FORMAT and one set in the session. It would still be helpful to see your actual output from the two queries. But @Rene is still right - wrap each of your queries in `dump()` and you'll see different types reported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the [`decode`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm#i1017437) function result has the datatype of the third parameter. In the first case, since no datatype is specified for `NULL`, the default VARCHAR2 is used. In the second case, a DATE is explicitely asked for and therefore the result is a date.

In other words, the first query is the same as:

```
SELECT DECODE(SYSDATE, SYSDATE + 1, to_char(NULL), to_char(SYSDATE)) FROM DUAL;
```

The output of this query will be formatted as per your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter, while the second query will return a date which will be displayed according to your client settings.