# SQL Loader treating numbers as characters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, loader

I am trying to load data from a text file that is separated by a pipe "|" using the following control file:

```
OPTIONS (DIRECT = FALSE, SKIP = 2, ERRORS = 2147483647)
LOAD INTO TABLE <table>
APPEND FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS (
    desc    CHAR (4000),
    sl_no   CHAR (500),
    amt_var CHAR (4000),
    amt    "DECODE(NVL(LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(:amt_var, ' +-.0123456789E',' '))),0),0,:amt_var,0)"
)
```

Here `amt_var` is `CHAR(4000)`, `amt` is `FLOAT`. The `amt_var` column is loaded with data from the flat file which could be float numbers or text which is why I am using `TRANSLATE` to identify and accordingly save numbers in `amt` field.

**Problem**: Upon loading, all data in column: `amt` is showing as `0.0`. In other words, all data in that column is interpreted as characters and not numbers. However, I can clearly see that that most of the data in the column are numbers. What could be the reason?

Sample Data:

```
Header Title|Line||
Desc|Line|Amount
Some text here |ABCD0001|58847811
Some text here |ABCD0002|111881
Some text here |ABCD0003|1571
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Decode function results with different formats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853420/oracle-decode-function-results-with-different-formats)

Comment: I've managed to resolve this issue. Apparently, the reason of the anomaly was a carriage return that was automatically getting added to the end of the column. This was resolved by using dos to unix conversion.